# How to fill missing data according to the date previous and next to it in R?

Tags: r, datetime

Two more questions about this topic:
[A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53302125/how-to-compare-with-a-reference-date-then-fill-missing-data-in-r)
[B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314087/warning-error-when-filling-missing-data-in-r)

Take Fig.1 as an example, we can see that data in 10/12/2016 12:07 is missing. I want to use the previous and next row of data (i.e., 10/10/2016 10:50    5.73; 10/24/2016 08:53  6.09) to linear interpolate this missing data (not the mean value of "5.73" and "6.09", but 
 according to the "date").  The example data file is attached below:

```
09/26/2016 11:57    5.42
10/10/2016 10:50    5.73
10/12/2016 12:07    
10/24/2016 08:53    6.09
11/07/2016 11:25    6.43
11/21/2016 13:57    6.33
12/05/2016 14:01    7.97
12/19/2016 13:00    8.47
```

You can see Fig.2, we can use "Trend()" to attain this goal.

```
=TREND(M22:M23,L22:L23,O22)
```

I was wondering if there is a useful function as well in R?

[image: Fig-1]
 [image: Fig-2]

Comment: Pls post data no pictures! Check out `?dput`.

Comment: You could do a weighted average, so if the previous date is closer to the missing date it's weighted more.

Comment: Have a look at `difftime`. Then you can get two time differences: "before and missing" and "missing and after". The value you can interpolate by "value before" + "value after" * diff1 / (diff1 + diff2)

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't post data. I have uploaded it.@vaettchen

Comment: Thanks!@CIAndrews. Yet I'am afraid your equation should be: "value before" + "value after - value before" * diff1 / (diff1 + diff2)

Comment: @mickey What you said is exactly what I want to do. Do you know some "functions" that can be  convenient to use?

Comment: That sound like something `tweenr` could do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(date = mdy_hm(
                    c("10/10/2016 10:50",
                      "10/12/2016 12:07",
                      "10/24/2016 08:53")),
            figure = c(5.73, NA_real_, 6.09))
```

Using the `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)    
library(magrittr)

zoo(df$figure, df$date) %>% 
      na.approx() %>% 
      as.data.frame()
```

Using `lubridate` and `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
   mutate(figure = ifelse(is.na(figure),
                      lag(figure, 1) + (lead(figure, 1) - lag(figure, 1)) *
                      as.numeric(difftime(date, lag(date, 1))) / 
                      as.numeric((difftime(lead(date, 1), date) + difftime(date, lag(date, 1)))),
                      figure)) %>% 
   mutate(figure = round(figure, 2))
```

Comment: Appreciate it. I tried your code, and the result is "13.92" for "2016-10-12 12:07:00". However, I think this value may be wrong. Because what I want to fill is like CIAndrews says in Comments. So the result should be "5.78". You can see my edited question, I have changed it with an example in Excel.

Comment: Updated following your comment.

Comment: I was wondering if you could see the question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53302125/how-to-compare-with-a-reference-date-then-fill-missing-data-in-r) when you have time. This extra question is another 50% part of the whole "missing data" problem.