# How to compare with a "reference date", then fill missing data in R?

Tags: r, datetime

Two more questions about this topic:
[A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53292882/how-to-fill-missing-data-according-to-the-date-previous-and-next-to-it-in-r)
[B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314087/warning-error-when-filling-missing-data-in-r)

First, let me show the example data (Data A & B):

(1) Data A:

```
Date_Collected  A_Value
01/04/2016 10:53    0.137
01/20/2016 13:13    0.204
01/25/2016 11:09    0.199
02/01/2016 12:55    0.441
02/01/2016 12:56    0.215
02/01/2016 13:11    0.397
02/03/2016 09:19    0.377
02/10/2016 08:11    1.45
02/15/2016 13:04    2.63
```

(2) Data B:

```
Date_Collected  B_Value
01/04/2016 10:53    0.108
01/20/2016 13:13    0.404
02/01/2016 13:11    0.594
02/15/2016 13:04    1.99
```

Second, I will tell what I want to do with R. You can see that "Data A" has 9 records, while "Data B" has only 4 records. As these values are so precious, I will not delete "Data A" to fit the rows of "Data B". Instead, I will fill the "missing" data in "Data B". The things need to do can be separated into two parts:

(Part Ⅰ)
① To add blank rows for "Data B" in the corresponding location, according to "Data A"; ② In these blank rows (blue in Fig.1), copy the corresponding date. The result at the end of Part Ⅰ is like Fig.1.

(Part Ⅱ)
To interpolate the missing data in "B_Value". This part has been solved. You can see the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53292882/how-to-fill-missing-data-according-to-the-date-previous-and-next-to-it-in-r?noredirect=1#comment93473298_53292882) of Stack Overflow.

Could someone give me advice about it (especially Part Ⅰ)? Thanks.

[image: Fig-1]

Comment: u can use join or left join or full join based on the requirment

Comment: You can also use the function `complete` from `tidyr` package to do both part ! and II at the same time. If you post your data using `dput` I'll be able to help you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

# example data
dt_A = data.frame(Date = c("01/04/2016 10:53", "02/04/2016 10:54", "03/04/2016 10:55"),
                  A_Value = c(5,6,7))

dt_B = data.frame(Date = c("01/04/2016 10:53", "03/04/2016 10:55"),
                  B_Value = c(1,3))

# complete dates of data B using dates of data A
dt_B %>% complete(Date = dt_A$Date)


# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Date             B_Value
#   <chr>              <dbl>
# 1 01/04/2016 10:53       1
# 2 02/04/2016 10:54      NA
# 3 03/04/2016 10:55       3
```

Comment: I met one warning and one error when using your advice (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314087/warning-error-when-filling-missing-data-in-r). Please help me when you have time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using *merge*:

```
# data stolen from @AntoniosK's post
dt_A = data.frame(Date = c("01/04/2016 10:53", "02/04/2016 10:54", "03/04/2016 10:55"),
                  A_Value = c(5,6,7))

dt_B = data.frame(Date = c("01/04/2016 10:53", "03/04/2016 10:55"),
                  B_Value = c(1,3))

# keep dates as date
dt_A$Date <- as.POSIXct(dt_A$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
dt_B$Date <- as.POSIXct(dt_B$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

# then merge and sort on date
res <- merge(dt_B, dt_A[, "Date", drop  = FALSE], all.y = TRUE)
res <- res[ order(res$Date), ]
res
#                  Date B_Value
# 1 2016-01-04 10:53:00       1
# 2 2016-02-04 10:54:00      NA
# 3 2016-03-04 10:55:00       3
```

Comment: I may not express my requirement clearly. But your method seems to add the "NA" row at the end, not "in the middle" of two dates (see AntoniosK's result).

Comment: @TX Keep your date column as date class, then you could sort it as: `res <- res[ order(res$Date), ]`

Comment: @TX Updated the post.